# LWC Insufficient access

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, standard-objects, insufficient-privileges

When trying to access standard Lead object in LWC, I encounter an error.

> errorCode :  "INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS" message :  "You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help or to request access.

Code

```
import { api, wire, track, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import LEAD_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Lead';

export default class TestComponent extends LightningElement {
    // Get Object Info.
    @wire (getObjectInfo, {objectApiName: LEAD_OBJECT})
    getLeadInfo({data, error}) {
        if(data){
            console.log(' Object information ', data);
            console.table(data);
        }
        if(error){
            console.log('ERROR');
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
```

I am system administrator profile

[image]

Comment: No access to account as well

Comment: Where your component is placed? In internal salesforce or in a community (experience cloud)?